# AngularJS ngRepeat orderBy not working in Chrome

Tags: angularjs

When the controller is initially loaded with data, I want the rows to appear in the same order they were added to my JSON.

When I do this in IE and FF, the rows intially appear in the order they were added, but when I do it in Chrome, the middle item (in this case row #150) appears at the beginning of the list. Why is this?

**I have Json response,**

```
    [
      {
        "code": "4001",
        "description": "Transactions",
        "labelName": null,
        "target": null,
         "sortOrder": 100,
        "iconTarget": "fa-inr"
      },
      {
        "code": "4053",
        "description": "Cash Management",
        "labelName": null,
        "target": null,
        "sortOrder": 150,
        "iconTarget": "fa-money"
      },
      {
        "code": "4053",
        "description": "Cash Management",
        "labelName": null,
        "target": null,
        "sortOrder": 500,
        "iconTarget": "fa-money"
      }
    ]
```

### template

```
<ul class="panel sidebar-nav" ng-repeat="item in model | orderBy: -item.sortOrder">    
 <li>child links data</li>
 <li>child links data</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Why are using - with **orderBy: -item.sortOrder"**

Comment: The orderby only works with the array.

Refer this:
<https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, just missing single quotes around your expression.  Also, you don't need to refer to the ng-repeat name "item", only its attribute.  Your code should read something like

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in model | orderBy: 'sortOrder'">
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y3faKaQ8XIpMojq5iBe7?p=preview).

Comment: still i am getting the same issue

Comment: What happens if you change the order of your model in FF?

Comment: Ahhh I had a typo, you don't need to refer to the model name from the ng-repeat.  You just need the attribute name 'sortOrder'.  Updated my answer, try like that.

Comment: Did anybody find a solution for Chrome?

Comment: Large collections in Chrome are not ordered correctly. In FF and IE it works as expected. Is this a known bug? Is this fixed in a newer version of Angular?

Answer (score -3):

change the angularjs version 1.5.x. It works for me.

Comment: I think this is an answer.  It might be unhelpful, but it's definitely an answer.